# Create MySQL query to create a table from an existing table

Tags: mysql

I have quite a large and complex table in a MySQL database that would be a pain to have to build a query for manually to recreate if anything went wrong.

Is there someway I can get MySQL or some other tool/script I can use to get a Query made automatically that would recreate the structure of the table?

Ideally if you suggested a tool/script it would be for Linux

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `thetable`;
```

Also any backup method like `mysqldump` should give you an option to save structure as well as data.

Comment: wow as simple as that, either my google skills are lacking or my eyes weren't working

Answer (score 19):

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

Answer (score 15):

execute these queries :

> If you want to copy table structure with primary key, foreign key and
>   constrains with data...

```
CREATE TABLE newtableName LIKE oldTableName; 
INSERT newtableName SELECT * FROM oldTableName;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the mysqldump tool to export the structure and data of a mysql table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> <database_name> --no-data --tables <table_name> > table.ddl

Answer (score 3):

`CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 =0`

Comment: Creates the new table with the same structure but, does not copy over the primary key to the new table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can export the structure of the table from phpmyadmin to a sql file...

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with other folks:
with mysqldump you get a dump of your table (option --tables),  let's say dumpMyTable.sql
then if you want to load this dump on a new schema:

```
mysql -uuser_name -ppassword MyNewSchema < dumpMyTable.sql
```

if you want to load it in the same schema but in a new table you will have to edit the dumpMyTable.sql file and change the name of the table manually. If the dump file is very big, I recommend the use of the "sed" command

Answer (score 0):

You may use SqlYog for this purpose. Solution is just 2 clicks away from this tool. You may use DataBase menu for this purpose. You can also copy only the schema or the whole data and both to even different servers.